# How to fix "The remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sms, webclient

I've created asp.net web-api , In the controller I try to call an external URL to send sms(the sms URL I get from the sms provider company )

> When I try to call the controller I get this error 
>    "The remote name could not be resolved"
>
> #### This error only happened on the server ,On the localhost it's working fine

I am using Azure hosting

1. I tried to add some code to the webconfig

```
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
```

2. I also tried to call the sms URL in a different way

```
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters);
```

3. I've read some solutions about allowing access for the external link(SMS) on firewall and DNS of the server but it's already configured on azure server

Here is my code

```
    string webAddress = "http://----------------";
    string SomeData = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString((new 
    System.Net.WebClient()).DownloadData(webAddress));
```

I want my web api to send the sms without any error on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ,I solved the problem by replacing the SMS provider URL by their IP Address.
Here is an example of my solution :

> Ex : http://123.123.123.123:12345/TEST/Para?i1=